# Tikz external files and pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, pdftex, matlab

I plot graph in my article with the command '\begin{tikzpicture} ..\end{tikzpicture}'. First, I extract datas from matlab in a text file and I use  \addplot with all the options. It is great, but my compilation is very very long ( I have a lot of figures ). Is it possible to have all the figures in tikz external files ( which I can modify sometimes ) and convert into a pdf file (because using \includegraphics with a pdf file is very fast) ?

Answer (score 6):

You can process your `tikzpicture`s as standalone documents and then include them as pictures. E.g., the file `myplot.tex` might contain

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[...]
  ...
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Your main document then includes the generated pdfs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{myplot.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

My advise is to put the tikz-code of your plots in separate files as it is easier to manage. I use an alias for `\input` to include these files just in case it requires special treatment later on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\tikzinput}[1]{%
    \input{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tikzinput{myplot.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Second, you should use `\tikzexternalize` to speed up compilation. See the pgfplots manual: *7.1.1 Using the Automatic Externalization Framework of TikZ*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize% activate externalization!

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both of you! I don't why, but it does not for one for my figure. I have a double figure which is 4 tikz pictures. ( \begin{figure} \begin{minipage} 2 tikz picture \end{minipage} \end {figure} + the same for the 2 others ). How can i do that?

Comment: You should create a new question with a minimal example and don't forget to specify your environment (pdflatex, windows, ...).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `tikzexternalize` if the document is *stable* and you 
will make few modifications to `tikzpicture`,  it is better to handle it in 
separate files and include them as an image (or with `\input{file-tkz-1.tex}`). 
The `ltximg` script you can do the following:

```
$ ltximg --subenv --imgdir=mypics --prefix=tkz -o test-out test-in.tex
```

Now you will have a document with the `tikzpicture` environments converted into 
images (preserving the consistency of the fonts) and you will also have each 
`tikzpicture` environment in separate files (in case you need some extra 
modification). First check the documentation to see the options and conditions 
that the input file must meet.